# Convert Public Key from PuTTY Windows Format to Mac Format

Tags: ssh, openssh

I need to convert my PrivateKey and PublicKey from my windows machine to Mac under `.ssh` folder.

This done for PrivateKey and I converted it successfully, but not for PublicKey.

I have tried many times using different command, but with no luck.

Comment: This question would be more appropriate at http://apple.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

If you've transferred the private key already, the public key can be derived from that. Use ssh-keygen -y.

Comment: After executing ssh-keygen -y I have asked to the "Enter In Which File The Key is (The PrivateKey Directory)". Which File I should add here?

Comment: That's your private key, which you said in your question you'd already transferred.

Comment: Yeah, you'd put the path to that file. Or if you've already got your private key in ~/.ssh, you should be able to just hit enter and accept the default.